# Validating bad imported data in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The scenario is typical.  User asks me to import a spreadsheet into a table - Mastertable.

Mastertable has a PK of acct and FK of ProviderID.

The import goes poorly, about 10% of records lost due to key violations.  I think this is due to specifying a providerID that does not exist.

Is there a way I can figure out which providerIDs are bad?  I can import into a fresh table - "MasterTableNew", but when I do a select like this:

```
SELECT acct FROM MastertableNew 
WHERE NOT EXIST (
   SELECT Mastertable.acct 
   FROM Mastertable 
   INNER JOIN MastertableNew 
   ON Mastertable.acct = MastertableNew.acct)
```

it turns up blank - I am expecting to see rows that exist in MastertableNew that do not exist in Mastertable.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT acct FROM MastertableNew 
LEFT JOIN Mastertable ON MastertableNew.acct = Mastertable.acct
WHERE Mastertable.acct Is Null
```

Comment: Meh. "Type Mismatch in expression" This is my exact query (note here i am using another table, but the concept is exactly the same).SELECT CDNew.acct, CDNew.ID
FROM CDNew LEFT JOIN ChartDetail ON CDNew.[acct] = ChartDetail.[acct]
WHERE (((ChartDetail.acct) Is Null));

Comment: Ignore above, I imported acct as a text field and it needs to be a number to match with the existing table.  This works fine, thanks!